# R grouping based on time difference

Tags: r, group-by

Here is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(col_1 = c('11/13/2007', '11/17/2007', '11/19/2007', '11/25/2007', '11/28/2007'),
                 col_2 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))
```

I would like to add column, which would group elements using time difference of dates in `col_1`. For example first, second and third rows will be in group 1, since dates differ only by less than 5 days (between each consecutive dates) and row four and five will be in group 2. We will get two groups since two consecutive dates '11/19/2007' and '11/25/2007' differ by more than 5 days.

I can compute day difference between dates, but now sure how to create grouping. I would prefer solution with `dplyr`, but any piece of advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could create the groups without have to do anything particularly fancy.

First we clean `col_1` then get the groups. Note I create `lag_time_diff` to help with readability but you can choose to put it directly in the `cumsum` if you want.

```
df$col_1 <- as.POSIXct(df$col_1, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

lag_time_diff <- difftime(df$col_1, lag(df$col_1, default = df$col_1[1]), units = "days")
df$group <- cumsum(ifelse(lag_time_diff>5,1,0))


df
#       col_1 col_2 group
#1 2007-11-13     A     0
#2 2007-11-17     B     0
#3 2007-11-19     C     0
#4 2007-11-25     D     1
#5 2007-11-28     E     1
```

All this does is check if the lagged difference in times is >5, if it is it indexes by 1 otherwise it keeps the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This approach creates a final product with some redundant info, so there is definitely a more efficient way to go about it, but this seems to satisfy your dilemma:

```
## generate data
df <- data.frame(col_1 = c('11/13/2007', 
                           '11/17/2007', 
                           '11/19/2007', 
                           '11/25/2007', 
                           '11/28/2007'),
                 col_2 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))

## convert date to date class
df$col_1 <- as.Date(as.character(df$col_1), format = "%m/%d/%Y")

## define function for difftime variable
foo <- function(d1, d) sapply(d, function(x) difftime(d1, x))

## apply function to each observation and convert to data frame
dfdat <- structure(
    data.frame(sapply(df$col_1, foo, df$col_1)),
    names = as.character(df$col_1))

## combine with original data
df <- cbind(df, dfdat)

## use tidyr package to make long form
df <- tidyr::gather(df, referent, difftime, -col_1, -col_2)

## load dplyr 
library(dplyr)

## use dplyr to mutate and group
df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(referent = as.Date(referent)) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(difftime)
```

> Source: local data frame [25 x 4]
>       Groups: difftime [19]
>
> ```
>         col_1  col_2   referent difftime
>        <date> <fctr>     <date>    <dbl>
> 1  2007-11-13      A 2007-11-13        0
> 2  2007-11-17      B 2007-11-13       -4
> 3  2007-11-19      C 2007-11-13       -6
> 4  2007-11-25      D 2007-11-13      -12
> 5  2007-11-28      E 2007-11-13      -15
> 6  2007-11-13      A 2007-11-17        4
> 7  2007-11-17      B 2007-11-17        0
> 8  2007-11-19      C 2007-11-17       -2
> 9  2007-11-25      D 2007-11-17       -8
> 10 2007-11-28      E 2007-11-17      -11
> # ... with 15 more rows
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really quickly with base R.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(col_1 = c('11/13/2007', '11/17/2007', '11/19/2007', '11/25/2007', '11/28/2007'),
                 col_2 = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))

df$col_1 = as.Date(df$col_1, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

df$group = rleid(cumsum(c(0, diff.Date(df$col_1) > 5)))

> df
       col_1 col_2 group
1 2007-11-13     A     1
2 2007-11-17     B     1
3 2007-11-19     C     1
4 2007-11-25     D     2
5 2007-11-28     E     2
```

Comment: `rleid` is from `data.table`

Comment: @Nova Thanks, I added the library.