# Group by based on two columns and create a new column to calculate time difference based on each group

Tags: r, date, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset which comprises of the supplier id, buyer id and the transaction date. Here's a sample dataset:

```
df= data.frame(supplier_id= c("176", "345", "343", "766", "766", "766", "278", "341", "341","890","789","687","787","787"), buyer= c("wang","cheng","li","cheng","cheng",
"cheng","li","wang","wang","Echo","Kelly","Kelly","cheng","cheng"), date=c("2/20/2018","2/26/2018",
"1/2/2019","4/10/2018","4/10/2018","4/10/2018","4/18/2018","4/18/2018","1/5/2019","2/23/2018","2/23/2018","6/29/2017","6/20/2017","5/11/2017"))

df$date=as.Date(df$date, format="%m/%d/%y")
```

There are 2 parts to this question. The first part of this problem is to arrange the dataset in such a way that we have same buyers and same suppliers grouped together and arranged in ascending order of buyer's name, along with ascending order of date for each group separately. The data will then look something like the following:

```
| supplier_id | Buyer |      date |
|-------------|:-----:|----------:|
| 345         | cheng | 2/26/2018 |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 |
|             |       |           |
| 890         | Echo  | 6/29/2017 |
|             |       |           |
| 789         | Kelly | 5/11/2017 |
| 687         | Kelly | 6/20/2017 |
|             |       |           |
| 343         | li    | 1/2/2019  |
| 278         | li    | 1/5/2019  |
|             |       |           |
| 176         | wang  | 2/20/2018 |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 |
```

The second part of the problem is to identify the transactions that occurred within a span of 5 days. So, we will be creating a new column, which would then calculate the date difference and the data with a new column would then be:

```
| supplier_id | Buyer |      date | date_diff |
|-------------|:-----:|----------:|-----------|
| 345         | cheng | 2/26/2018 | 43        |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 | 0         |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 | 0         |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 | 8         |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 | 0         |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 | NA        |
|             |       |           |           |
| 890         | Echo  | 6/29/2017 | NA        |
|             |       |           |           |
| 789         | Kelly | 5/11/2017 | 40        |
| 687         | Kelly | 6/20/2017 | NA        |
|             |       |           |           |
| 343         | li    | 1/2/2019  | 3         |
| 278         | li    | 1/5/2019  | NA        |
|             |       |           |           |
| 176         | wang  | 2/20/2018 | 3         |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 | 0         |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 | NA        |
```

Then, I need to select all those dates which had transactions in a gap of 5 days. So, that would be date_diff <=5, but, if I go by this logic, it would exclude the date "4/10/2018" (the 4th record), since the date difference between 4/10/2018 and 4/18/2018 is 8. However, there are 3 transactions occuring on 4/10/2018, so I would be interested in getting all the 3 dates. I first thought of using "elseif", but that does not eliminate my problem of retaining the date '4/10/2018' and I have too many of such cases in my original dataset. I'm clueless about this approach.

I tried using group_by and mutate to group the buyers and supplier_id and then create a new column to calculate the date difference, but, my code is not giving the desired output.

```
df1=df %>% group_by(buyer, supplier_id) %>% 
  mutate(diffdate= difftime(date,lag(date,1),units='days'))
```

I could also use 'arrange' function, but that would just arrange the dataset in ascending order and not group the data by buyers and supplier_id to calculate the date difference.

My expected output should be:

```
| supplier_id | Buyer | date      |
|-------------|-------|-----------|
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 766         | cheng | 4/10/2018 |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 |
| 787         | cheng | 4/18/2018 |
|             |       |           |
| 343         | li    | 1/2/2019  |
| 278         | li    | 1/5/2019  |
|             |       |           |
| 176         | wang  | 2/20/2018 |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 |
| 341         | wang  | 2/23/2018 |
```

Can someone please help me in this problem set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R grouping based on time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899898/r-grouping-based-on-time-difference)

Comment: @kstew But I need to group the buyers and supplier_id first and the calculation of difference in dates needs to be done based on each group separately. So, for example in the above dataset, the dates for each buyer group should be considered separately and not to be considered with other group while calculating date difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. For each unique buyer-date combination, you create the range of dates (+/- 5 days) that could be included using `tidyr::complete`. Then join your original data and calculate your summary statistics. I have added a 'value' column to illustrate this.

```r
df$value <- runif(nrow(df))

df1 <- df %>% arrange(buyer,date) %>% distinct(buyer,date) %>% 
  mutate(date.orig=date) %>% 
  group_by(buyer,date,date.orig) %>% 
  complete(date=seq(from=(date-5),to=(date+5),by=1))

df1 %>% left_join(df) %>% group_by(buyer,date.orig) %>% 
  summarise(s=sum(value,na.rm=1),n=sum(!is.na(value)))
```

Unfortunately, your example data does not really provide a good test for this solution, as only Cheng has multiple transactions on one day and no buyer has multiple transactions within the 5-day window.